# How to add products dynamically in redux initial state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, next.js

I am facing complexity on how to add dynamic products in the redux initial state in the next.js redux part?

Currently in my initial state something like that:

```
const initState = {
    products: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Long Sleeve Leopard T-Shirt",
            price: 250,
            image: require("../../images/products/img1.jpg")
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Gildan Men's Crew T-Shirt",
            price: 150,
            image: require("../../images/products/img4.jpg")
        }],
    addedItems:[],
    total: 0,
    shipping: 0
}
```

That is static and now I want load products here dynamically from a server like Firebase.

I was tried creating a function like addToCart() which is currently working for adding products into the cart but didn't luck on that.

You can see my current cartReducer file from the below link.

[**Here is the Gist**](https://gist.github.com/shabbir-ahmed/ef23ca87641de6f7ec8f0b825b89a0ca)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

When you load data dynamically from a server, you can use actions and reducers to update the **current** state. The initial state should just be an empty object or list. You don't change the initial state dynamically. Instead, you update the current state as you load data.

Comment: Apologize! How would I do that? I was tried something like the addToCart() function & it called from componentDidMount but it's not called automatically. Have you any examples of that, please?

Comment: @user9769384 here you can find it https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts

Comment: @user9769384, you should be planning to have application state that represents the state before the initial data has arrived from the server.  A veritable "loading please wait" state.  Even this isn't your initial state, which should be nearly completely empty.  Your componentDidMount fires off a fetch, and you respond by entering the "loading" state (display pacifier), and when data arrives, update state to display your lists of "initially fetched" data